# How to creat an interactive email in outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

Hi i have a task to create an interactive email in Outlook. Mail contains couple questions for survey mostly Yes or No as answers. So i wanted to use checkboxes or radio buttons...etc. And also if the 1st & 2nd questions are answered as Yes following questions should be visible.

I have done the 1st part of checkboxes using MSWord, but have no clue on how to hide n show the questions depending upon given condition.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not run any scripts or forms in HTML emails both for security purposes and because HTML is rendered by Word, not Internet Explorer.

Comment: Streblec : Do you mean we cannot do something like this in outlook ??

Comment: Correct. You cannot do that.